# Any easier way of sorting this table based on dynamic sort parameter and direction?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a procedure that produces a table that is sorted based on the initial parameters supplied to it.  This is what I'm having to do to sort it:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Description' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN s.[Description] END) ASC,
            (CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Description' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN s.[Description] END) DESC,
            (CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'SiteId' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN t.SiteId END) ASC,
            (CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'SiteId' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN t.SiteId END) DESC,
            (CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'CancerConfirmed' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN t.CancerConfirmed END) ASC,
            (CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'CancerConfirmed' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN t.CancerConfirmed END) DESC,
            (CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'NoCancer' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN t.NoCancer END) ASC,
            (CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'NoCancer' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN t.NoCancer END) DESC,
            (CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'SuspectCancer' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN t.SuspectCancer END) ASC,
            (CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'SuspectCancer' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN t.SuspectCancer END) DESC,
            (CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'TotalCancer' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN t.TotalCancer END) ASC,
            (CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'TotalCancer' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN t.TotalCancer END) DESC,
            (CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'NoFirstAppointment' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN t.NoFirstAppointment END) ASC,
            (CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'NoFirstAppointment' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN t.NoFirstAppointment END) DESC,
            (CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'NoTreatment' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN t.NoTreatment END) ASC,
            (CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'NoTreatment' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN t.NoTreatment END) DESC,
            (CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'NoDecisionToTreat' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN t.NoDecisionToTreat END) ASC,
            (CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'NoDecisionToTreat' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN t.NoDecisionToTreat END) DESC,
            (CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'InterTrustDiscussion' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN itd.InterTrustDiscussion END) ASC,
            (CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'InterTrustDiscussion' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN itd.InterTrustDiscussion END) DESC,
            (CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'InterTrustTransfer' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN i.InterTrustTransfer END) ASC,
            (CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'InterTrustTransfer' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN i.InterTrustTransfer END) DESC,
            (CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'WaitingOnInvestigation' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN w.WaitingOnInvestigation END) ASC,
            (CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'WaitingOnInvestigation' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN w.WaitingOnInvestigation END) DESC,
            (CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Oncology' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN o.Oncology END) ASC,
            (CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Oncology' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN o.Oncology END) DESC
```

I'm no SQL expert, so this is the best I an come up with.  Does anyone know of a better way or more succinct way this could be done?  I doubt it, just thought I'd ask.

Comment: This is screaming for Dynamc SQL.

Comment: See [this](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html#SortOrder), but then [this](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html#sp_executesql) (and then read the whole rest of it anyway).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks, this is the best way forward.  Put this in as the answer.